# Auth error trying to copy repo with Github Actions, take 2

Tags: git, github, github-actions

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64270867/474349), per @bk2204's request.

I'm trying to mirror a repo from one org to another using Github Actions. The step in question is:

```
  - name: Copy to Cloudyr
    if: runner.os == 'Linux' # && github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    env:
      token: "${{ secrets.ghPat }}"
    run: |
      export CLOUDYR_REPO=$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | sed "s/Azure/cloudyr/")
      git config -l | grep 'http\..*\.extraheader' | cut -d= -f1 | \
        xargs -L1 git config --unset-all
      git push --prune https://token:$token@github.com/${CLOUDYR_REPO}.git +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

However, this results in an error:

```
Run export CLOUDYR_REPO=$(echo $GITHUB_REPOSITORY | sed "s/Azure/cloudyr/")
To https://github.com/cloudyr/AzureAuth.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master)
 ! [remote rejected] origin/fix-ghaction -> fix-ghaction (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/cloudyr/AzureAuth.git'
```

How can I fix this? I have admin access to both the repos in question.

Failed log is here: https://github.com/Azure/AzureAuth/runs/1228871427?check_suite_focus=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a repository with GitHub Actions, by default it clones it in a particular way:

- First, it uses the `--depth=1` option to make a shallow clone.
- Second, it clones only the single ref that you're using.

Both of these result in a much smaller amount of data being cloned which makes runs potentially much faster.  However, in your case, this has a few problems that prevent it from working the way you want it:

- First, you cannot push from this shallow clone to a new repository because your Actions repository may lack objects needed for the push (resulting in “shallow update not allowed").
- Second, you haven't cloned any branch but the single one you're testing, so you're implicitly trying to delete every other branch.  However, you're not allowed to delete the default branch (in this case, `master`), so you get the error “refusing to delete the current branch”.

What you want to do is fetch all history for all branches and tags, so you should pass an appropriate option:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    fetch-depth: 0
```

That will result in a full clone at the expense of increased time, but it will allow you to push your repository elsewhere.