# GitHub workflow `Process completed with exit code 128`

Tags: github, workflow, cicd

Our GitHub has a development repository (`https://github.com/company_name/app_name`). In the development repository, there is a dev branch which not allow direct merge. All developers working on the development repository have to create their forked repository and create a feature branch tracking their forked repository. When a new PR is created, the newly created PR will target the dev branch in the development repository.

I have the following GitHub workflow job to run a Python script that updates the version in a header file and then commits the modified version file when a new PR is opened/reopened.

```
name: Bump FW version

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - "opened"
      - "reopened"

permissions:
  contents: write

env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GIT_CLONE_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  bump-version:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: "Config Git"
        run: |
          git config --global url."https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/".insteadOf "git@github.com:"
          git config --global user.email "${{ github.actor }}@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --global user.name "${{ github.actor }}"

      - name: run version bumping script
        run: |
          pwd
          echo "Bumping the FW version ..."
          cd Door
          ./tools/scripts/bump_version.py
      - name: Commit and push the version update
        run: |
          pwd
          git remote -v
          git add ./app_name/src/version.h
          git commit -m "Automatically bump version"
          git fetch origin ${{ github.head_ref }}
          git rebase origin/${{ github.head_ref }}
          git push origin HEAD:${{ github.head_ref }}
```

However, If I opened a new PR `PR-Test-1`, the workflow failed to run and had the following error:

```
origin  https://github.com/company_name/app_name (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/company_name/app_name (push)
[detached HEAD 1a08dfb] Automatically bump version
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
fatal: couldn't find remote ref PR-Test-1
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Any suggestions to fix the error?

Edit 0:
Tried the following solutions, but no luck

[Auth error trying to copy repo with Github Actions, take 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64272276/auth-error-trying-to-copy-repo-with-github-actions-take-2)

[How to push to another repository in github actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374179/how-to-push-to-another-repository-in-github-actions) (git config --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader)

Edit 1:
Based on https://github.com/EndBug/add-and-commit?tab=readme-ov-file#working-with-prs The checked out branch on the runner is detached by default. Not know why GitHub made the decision.